# How is ANOVA related to general linear models?

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model

I am new to stats and this is a silly question, but I just cannot see how ANOVA is related to general linear models.

I am learning about GLM and all the materials I found are saying that ANOVA is a kind of general linear model. for example: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/216

I can see how GLM is extended from multiple linear regression, but ANOVA is just the ratio: "variance between" over "variance within". How is it GLM?

Comment: You use the term *general linear models* in the title and the question, but the link you sent discusses about the *generalized linear models* (and you used this tag). In the link, they distinguished these terms to clarify the terminology. I think you are asking about *generalized linear models*, right?

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.